# mssql from docker-compose runs but master.mdf is missing

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose

I have the following compose service:

```
mssql:
container_name: MSSQL
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
ports:
 - 1433:1433
environment:
 - ACCEPT_EULA=Y 
 - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=bT!5P%4pRL4DK
 - MSSQL_DATA_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver/data
 - MSSQL_LOG_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver/log
 - MSSQL_BACKUP_DIR=/var/opt/sqlserver/backup
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-Usa", "-PbT!5P%4pRL4DK", "-Q", "select 1"]
  interval: 1s
  retries: 20
```

The SQL Server runs but says the following error:

> Server      Setup step is copying system data file 'C:\templatedata\master.mdf' to '/var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf'.
> 2023-09-24 10:15:09.16 Server      Did not find an existing master data file /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf, copying the missing default master and other system database files. If you have moved the database location, but not moved the database files, startup may fail. To repair: shutdown SQL Server, move the master database to configured location, and restart.

And the application cannot create the database.

Comment: That's an informational message in the errorlog when you first create an mssql server container - and is completely normal. Why can't your application create a database though? How does it try to do that? What error message(s) does it get?

Comment: The error message is that the database table is not found when the application wants to read it. The migration cannot connect to the database.

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77166636/edit) your question to include the full and complete text of the error message - as text, not screen shot(s). It sounds like you have a causality issue, i.e.: your migration is trying to connect to the database before the database has actually been created.